# Multiple upload of images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, upload, image-gallery

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am creating an app that can store photos in gallery. I have tried to upload a photo using paperclip and it is running successfully. But now I want to add multiple photos in same gallery at the same time using paperclip. I am not getting how to achieve it. Can anyone help me?

In gemfile I have written "gem 'paperclip'".

this are my models:

```
#Gallery Model
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :gallery_photos
 validates :name, presence: true
end

#GalleryPhoto Model
class GalleryPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :gallery
 has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
              :url  => "/assets/gallery_photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
              :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/gallery_photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

 validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png']
end
```

This is my Controller for gallery_photo:

```
def create

@gallery_photo = GalleryPhoto.new(gallery_photo_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @gallery_photo.save
    format.html { redirect_to galleries_galleryhome_path(id: @gallery_photo.gallery_id), notice: 'Gallery photo was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gallery_photo }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @gallery_photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
def gallery_photo_params
  params.require(:gallery_photo).permit(:gallery_id,:photo)
end
```

This is my migration file:

```
class AddAttachmentPhotoToGalleryPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  change_table :gallery_photos do |t|
   t.attachment :photo
  end
 end

 def self.down
   remove_attachment :gallery_photos, :photo
 end
end
```

In my view i have written the following line to attach images:

```
<%= form_for @gallery_photo,html: { multipart: true},url: gallery_photos_path,method: :post do |f| %>
  <div>
   <%= f.file_field :photo, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This are the Fields of the GalleryPhoto table:

```
class CreateGalleryPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gallery_photos do |t|
      t.references :gallery, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And Attachment Fields are added by the migration file that i have mentioned above.

Comment: What is the error throwing ?

Comment: It is not storing the atrributes of the images.

Comment: can you put the table fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to add the attachment related attributes to **gallery_photos** table

like

```
add_column :photos, :photo_file_name,:string
add_column :photos, :photo_content_type,:string
add_column :photos, :photo_file_size,:integer
add_column :photos, :photo_created_at,:datetime
```

Comment: As i have used paperclip, this fields are automatically added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

This line of your code failed

```
@gallery_photo = GalleryPhoto.new(gallery_photo_params)
```

because the `gallery_photo_params`'s value return by the form post is something like

```
{
    gallery_photo: { photo: [file1, file2,...] }
}
```

If you want to update multiple photos to a gallery. you need to update the gallery instead of gallery photo.

```
<%= form_for @gallery do |f| %>
  <div>
   <%= f.file_field :gallery_photos, multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and in your gallery controller

```
def update
  if @gallery.update(gallery_params)

    redirect_to some_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

It's the same if you want to create a gallery with multiple photos.

Comment: Thank you for the solution u suggested, but as i have created both the models with the scaffold. And i want to upload photos after the user goes to the home page of the gallery. There is a home page for gallery. User can navigate to this homepage through the list on index page of gallery. And on this home page the user is able to add photos from new page of gallery_photo that is navigated from a link on homepage of gallery.